# elasticsearch how to query hits near to a polygon

Tags: elasticsearch, polygon, geo

My Elasticsearch query is basically trying to answer,
**find all hits, near the city "X",** where city is of type Geo-shape polygon.

I want to find all points near a polygon,

Given a polygon with co-ordinates

```
"coordinates" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
          [
            [
              -91.014718,
              41.179923
            ],
            [
              -91.0144461,
              41.1655935
            ],
            [
              -91.012557,
              41.165922
            ],
            [
              -91.0096281,
              41.1660758
            ],
            [
              -91.007586,
              41.166183
            ],
            [
              -90.997906,
              41.162564
            ],
            [
              -90.99496,
              41.160624
            ],
            [
              -90.9925924,
              41.1584303
            ],
            [
              -91.014718,
              41.179923
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
```

i know, it's possible to query hits that fall **within** a polygon of points, But Will it be possible to query **near** of this polygon,

i am more interested to find hits that are (x Mi/Km) from boundary of polygon outside.

*I have thought of *one possible solution* would be by, treating each point of this polygon as independent point and finding the near hits of this point, and repeating this for all the points of the polygon. I am not very confident about this approach  so it would help, if you could point to the right direction*

Thanks.